# Diffrence between two android APIs

Tags: android, api, wifi

please someone can explain me what's the different between using android.net.wifi and android.net.wifi.p2p to use a Wireless network in android app developpment, i know that with the second one, we can use a Wifi without access point, but it's working juste with API 14 at least. what about the first ? is this working too without an access point, and does require API 14 at least ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

P2P is the api to connect to devices on an ap without internet connection

Comment: Okey, but it works just with level API 14 at least, then not all the andoid devices can use an application using this api.., it'isnt ?